# Number of paths subtractive approach

Tags: combinatorics

In such problems we're looking for the number of ways to go from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. I know how to solve these using Pascal's triangle as well as with the additive method (separating into cases), but I'm struggling to find the right method to subtract the "inaccessible paths" (i.e. top right and bottom left).

How can we effectively determine/calculate how many paths to remove? I know the strategy would be to imagine invisible points and to remove paths that go through those from the total number of paths, but I can't quite seem to understand the proper way to do it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider the number of paths to the two joint corners. If the top left is $(0,0),$ consider paths from $(0,0)$ to $(3,2)$ and then from $(3,2)$ to $(5,5).$ Do the same for $(2,3),$ (or use symmetry.

Comment: For this diagram, you get $2\binom52^2.$

Comment: In other circumstances, you might apply inclusion exclusion, considering all paths, and subtract paths that hit an unauthorized point. For example, if you remove $(2,2)$ and $(4,4)$ and you are going from $(0,0)$ to $(5,5)$ you can start with $\binom{10}5$ then subtract the $\binom{4}2\binom63$ paths going through $(2,2),$ the $\binom{8}{4}\binom{2}1$ that go through $(4,4),$ and then add back in the $\binom42\binom42\binom21$ which go through both, giving: $$\binom{10}5-\binom42\binom 63-\binom84\binom21+\binom42\binom42\binom21$$

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This makes sense. Now that works well if there's only two points to remove, but if there are a lot (or let's say in this case we want to remove all the red paths (updated picture in post), would there be any efficient way to do that?

Comment: I already gave an approach for this case in my first comment. Inclusion/exclusion is more useful when there are paths from one excluded point to another.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the strategy. It's just that I was reading an example in another forum (https://www.themathdoctors.org/how-many-paths-from-a-to-b/ - at the very end) where they seem to just subtract from the total and I was looking to apply that method with this problem. The strategy you mentioned is more efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but I need to post this image:

[image]

Find the number of paths to A, and then from A to the end.  Find the number of paths to B, and then from B to the end.

Add them.

But be clever:  Notice from the symmetry of the problem that the number of paths from start to A to end is the *same* as from end to B to start.

Answer (score 1):

A very general approach is to write it as a directed graph $G$ with $n$ nodes and no loop paths. Then write an incidence matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}=1$ if there is an edge from node $i$ to node $j,$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then show $A^{n}=0,$ and $B=(b_{ij})=I+A+\cdots +A^{n-1}=(I-A)^{-1}$ exists, and $b_{ij}$ is the number of paths from node $i$ to node $j.$

That can sometimes be a faster way, or at least can be computed by a computer.

Of course, this computes all paths.

This can be made faster and specific to two nodes just using recursion.

In this sort of checkerboard path count, you can separate the points $(i,j)$ by the distance from $(0,0).$

Then $p(i,j),$ the number of paths from $(0,0'$ to $(i,j)$ from $(0,0)$ to $(i,j)$ is zero if $(i,j)$ is excluded, $p(0,0)=1,$ and $p(i,j)=p(i-1,j)+p(i,j-1).$

This will take about $O(n)$ time to compute.